# Проблема во время создания телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я создаю бота для телеграмма для просмотра инфы про covid-19 и использую для этого библиотеки COVID19Py, requests
когда я выполняю этот

```
import COVID19Py

covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19()

location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("US")

print(location)
```

маленький кусок кода у меня выводится такая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    location = covid19.getLocationByCountryCode("US")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\COVID19Py\covid19.py", line 103, in getLocationByCountryCode
    data = self._request("/v2/locations", {"country_code": country_code})
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\COVID19Py\covid19.py", line 38, in _request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for url: https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations?country_code=US&source=jhu
```

как можно исправить это?

Comment: можно узнать кто и почему поставил минус

Comment: Ошибка говорит сама за себя: `503 Server Error: Service Unavailable`. Я вручную проверил сайт, он действительно лежит. *P. S.: минус не мой.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У меня этот код сработал. Ошибка 503 говорит о том, что сервер не был доступен во время запроса. Значит, ошибка не на твоей стороне